# Scaffolding with belongs_to and has_many relationships: link_to paths for "Edit" and "Destroy" not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many, scaffolding, belongs-to, link-to

My project allows a family page to have multiple stories.  The models include the relationships - "Family has_many stories" and "Story belongs to family".  In the routes.rb file I have the following:

```
resources :families do
    resources :stories   
  end
```

Resulting in the following routes for the stories controller:

```
    family_stories GET    /families/:family_id/stories(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"stories"}
                   POST   /families/:family_id/stories(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"stories"}
  new_family_story GET    /families/:family_id/stories/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"stories"}
 edit_family_story GET    /families/:family_id/stories/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"stories"}
      family_story GET    /families/:family_id/stories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"stories"}
                   PUT    /families/:family_id/stories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"stories"}
                   DELETE /families/:family_id/stories/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"stories"}
```

Here are the relevant controller methods:

```
  def edit
    @story = @family.stories.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @story = @family.stories.find(params[:id])
    @story.destroy
    redirect_to family_stories_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed story."
  end
```

For index.html.erb the code generated by nifty scaffolding does not take into account the relationships, and the links for the "Show", "Edit", and "Destroy" do not work.  After some research I modified the code for these links as follows:

```
  <% for story in @stories %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= story.title %></td>
      <td><%= story.body %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Show", [@family, story] %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_family_story_path([@family, story]) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Destroy", [@family,story], :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %> </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

The "Show" link works fine when replacing the original "story" variable with "[@family, story]".  The "Destroy" and "Edit" links do not work with similar substitutions.

The "Destroy" link develops no errors, but acts just like the "Show" link - the record is not deleted and is instead displayed (the :confirm dialog never shows.)  The "Edit" link generates the following error:

```
"No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"stories", :family_id=>\#[Story id: 1, title: "story01 for family01", body: "body01 for story01 for family01", created_at: "2011-04-09 22:55:14", updated_at: "2011-04-09 22:55:14", family_id: 1]}"
```

The [@family,story] construct works well for the "Show" link.  Why doesn't it work for the "Edit" and "Destroy" links?  How do I modify them to work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a conflicting javascript configuration.

The rails application builder that I used put my jquery.js file in the "public/javascript" folder, but within a folder call jquery (I had to move it up a level.) 2) the config/application.rb file had two javascript configuration lines. I deleted one and made sure the second one pointed to the jquery.js file mentioned above. With those to changes all worked